# How to rename a column which contains count function in a joined table in sql?

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to rename the Order_ID column as Orders. When I add 'AS Orders'  after the order_ID in 3rd line, it displays this kind of error
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
Do u guys have any idea on how to do that?

```
SELECT
    Rider_Name,
    COUNT(*) Order_ID 
FROM
    Rider r 
INNER JOIN
    Ordr o ON r.Rider_ID = o.Rider_ID
GROUP BY
    Rider_Name
HAVING
    COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY
    Order_ID
```

Comment: Please explain what you don't understand.  The answer seems really, really simple.

Comment: When I add 'AS Orders'  after the order_ID in 3rd line, it displays this kind of error...
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"

Comment: `count(*) as num_orders`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the old alias of Order_ID and add the new alias.

```
SELECT
    Rider_Name,
    COUNT(*) AS Orders
FROM
    Rider r 
INNER JOIN
    Ordr o ON r.Rider_ID = o.Rider_ID
GROUP BY
    Rider_Name
HAVING
    COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY
    Orders
```